# Multiple wordpress custom queries on one page

Tags: wordpress, loops

I'm trying to use multiple wordpress queries to show specific posts on specific pages, the problem is that once I do a query, I can't do another one. So for example:

```
$posts=new WP_Query($args = array ('posts_per_page'=>'1','tag_name'=>'frontpage1'));
while ( $posts->have_posts() ) {
    $posts->the_post(); 
    $arr['big']=array('id'=>get_the_id());
}

foreach(array(2,3,4,5) as $n){
    wp_reset_postdata();
    wp_reset_query();
    $posts=new WP_Query($args = array ('posts_per_page'=>'1','tag_name'=>'frontpage'.$n));
    while ( $posts->have_posts() ) {
        $posts->the_post(); 
        $arr['small'][$n]=array('id'=>get_the_id());
    }
}
```

Gives me this for $arr:

```
[big] => 
    [id] => 56714 
[small] => 
    [2] => [id] => 56714 
    [3] => [id] => 56714
    [4] => [id] => 56714
    [5] => [id] => 56714
```

The first one "big" is correct, but subsequent queries just loop through the same result. How do I reset the query?

Comment: Ahh I figured it out! It was a problem with the users, they'd put the tags in wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `wp_reset_postdata();` between each of the queries:

```
$posts=new WP_Query($args = array ('posts_per_page'=>'1','tag_name'=>'frontpage1'));
while ( $posts->have_posts() ) {
    $posts->the_post(); 
    $arr['big']=array('id'=>get_the_id());
}

wp_reset_postdata();

foreach(array(2,3,4,5) as $n){
    $posts=new WP_Query($args = array ('posts_per_page'=>'1','tag_name'=>'frontpage'.$n));
    while ( $posts->have_posts() ) {
        $posts->the_post(); 
        $arr['small'][$n]=array('id'=>get_the_id());
    }
}
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: Yeah i tried that too. Hold up, I'll put it in the code.

Comment: hmm.. sounds like the tagname doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $posts=new WP_Query($args = array ('posts_per_page'=>'1','tag'=>'frontpage'.$n));
```

Source:
[WP_Query tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Tag_Parameters)